# unique hit counter using file handling not working properly?

Tags: php

There are three files: index.php, ip.txt that contains ip address which are allowed to visit site and count.txt which simply counts the hit if any user visits the site with specified ip addresses in ip.txt. But the problem is when ip.txt contains only my laptops ip local machines ip address, it works perfectly and increases the ip address by one. But when ip.txt contains many ip address along with my local machines ip address if block in foreach loop checks them and and doesn't increase the count. However it should increase the count as my ip address is also there in ip.txt file. Please help!!

index.php:

```
<?php

$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$handle = fopen('ip.txt','r');
$file_read = fread($handle, filesize('ip.txt'));
$file_read_array = explode('\n',$file_read);

    foreach($file_read_array as $ip)
    {
        if(trim($ip) == trim($ip_address))
        {
            $visit =true;
            echo 'true';
            break;
        }       
        else
        {
            $visit =false;
            echo 'false';
        }
    }
    if($visit == true)
    {
        $handle_1 = fopen('count.txt','r');
        $file_read_1 = fread($handle_1, filesize('count.txt'));

        $increment = $file_read_1 + 1;
        fclose($handle_1);

        $handle_2 = fopen('count.txt','w');
        fwrite($handle_2,$increment);
        fclose($handle_2);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ip address not found.';
    }

?>
```

ip.txt:

127.0.0.1 
100.100.100.100 
102.1.1.1

count.txt:

0

Comment: Why don't you use `file()` instead of `fread()` + `explode( \n )` ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet I used that too and that is working perfectly, But as I am a newbie in php and leaning new concepts I want to make a unique hit count using this method too!!

Comment: does "count.txt" exists and does it actually contain "0" as content? Further, are you sure that your ip address is in the file? Have you echo'ed it out to check?

Comment: @Hirnhamster yes. count.txt does exists and it contain zero(0). And I am running it on my laptop or local server so my ip address is 127.0.0.1 which is there at the top in the ip.txt.

Comment: Please confirm by echoing it out. Your code is correct so it seems either your IP is not 127.0.0.1 or it is not part of $file_read_array

Comment: @Hirnhamster Confirmed!! I echoed it out and it's correct. This ip address is working perfectly with file() function but it's not working with fread() and explode() function.

Comment: Please post the full output of `var_dump($ip)` and `var_dump($file_read_array)` (edit your question, not as comment!)